# I'm finished == I'm ready?

Tags: sentence-meaning

I've read about the usage of ***finished*** as an adjective and have a question about it. Does the sentence

> I'm finished

express completely the same meaning as the sentence

> I'm ready

Comment: No. Why do you think they have the same meaning?

Comment: @user3169 Because finished can be used as an adjective after be meaning 'ready'.

Comment: Do you mean something like "Now I am finished working so I am ready to go home." Or could you write a sample phrase with the usage you mention?

Comment: @user3169 M. Swan doesn't provide an example for "I'm ready". He just says that an adjective "finished" can be meaning 'ready'.

Comment: @DmitryFucintv That fits to 'finished product' more. If a product is finished, it's *ready* (to use?).

Comment: Check this out: http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/finished. What Swan mentioned is sense 1. What you seem to be thinking of is sense 2. Be careful. Using it without a good context (that will make what you say make sense) could make your listeners think of sense 3.

Answer (score 1):

You use "***I'm finished***" in situations when you know you are *[dead meat](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Dead%20Meat)*, to indicate you are in some serious trouble. A similar expression would be "***[I'm done for](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/done+for)***".

However, there are some situations in informal conversations, where *I'm finished* is used to indicate *I'm ready*. Obviously, this is incorrect usage.

Comment: Could downvoter explain the reason? Is the answer is worng?

Comment: @DmitryFucintv I didn't down vote but I imagine it's because this is only one possible use of _I'm finished_ but this usage is not related to your question of _finished meaning ready_, unless ready to die is the intention.

Comment: @Manish Giri, I see your answer very good. Too bad that someone downvoted it without even knowing what they are doing.+1

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the context. Largely, *I'm finished' **is not equal to** 'I'm ready.* But if the scene is something like what I will now mention, *I'm finished' **is understood** as 'I'm ready.'*

> Come on buddy, let's go to movie ~ Sure, but let me complete my homework. Just 10 minutes.

And the friend waits in the room killing time by watching TV.

After 10 minutes...

> Jack, *I'm finished (with my homework).* Let's go

*[Finished](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/finished)* can be used to mean *no longer doing something or having thing completed.*

People do use this word that way as in [here](https://itd.sog.unc.edu/faq/2601-how-do-i-shut-down-room-when-i-am-finished), [here](http://www.italki.com/question/177592) and [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6052541?tstart=0). See that here, in no example, it means *someone is 'ready'.*

True, it's used as an adjective and it's quite similar to -*I'm done; I'm over with ...* etc.